# Last PrpcessedChangedDataTime in Azure DataFactory CDM is not reading values, giving only null

Tags: timestamp-with-timezone, azure-data-factory

I am facing issue with format 2022-10-07T03:12:32.2616992Z, what should be correct syntax? i have been using

"timestampFormats: ['yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS\'Z\'']) ~> DynamicsTage",

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the time format *'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'* and the value is read properly for the required data.

- Source file with two different date time formats is taken and added as a source in dataflow activity
  [image]

[image]

- Since there are two different formats in source, both timestamp formats are included in default format for time.

```
timestampFormats: ['yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS']) ~> source1
```

[image]

- Data is not null and it is read from source properly.
  [image]